# >A sphere of radius $7cm$ is put infront of light source at a distance of $15 m$ , what is area of "Illuminated" part of the sphere

Tags: geometry

Today , i had a math contest and the following problem was of the problems :-

> A sphere of radius $7cm$   is put infront of light source at a distance of $15 m$  , what is area of "Illuminated" part  of the sphere
>
> a)$105$ square metres.
>
> b)$\frac{105}{11}$  square metres  .
>
> c)$\frac{105}{22}$  square metres  .
>
> c)$210$  square metres .

Comment: I guess you mean a sphere with radius 7 _metres_, otherwise none of a) through d) makes sense. Moreover, you should make it precise what "distance" is: the distance of the nearest point of the sphere from the light source, or the distance of the center? The light source is meant to be a point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The illuminated part is a [spherical cap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap), with area
$$
S=2\pi R^2(1-\cos\theta).
$$
In the case at hand it is easy to see that
$$
\cos\theta={\hbox{sphere radius}\over\hbox{distance from sphere center to light source}}.
$$
To get one of the listed results, we must take $15$ metres to be the distance from the light source to the sphere surface, so that $\cos\theta=7/22$ and $S=209.9155\ldots$ square metres ($S=210$ if we take $\pi=22/7$).

Comment: Elegant solution  ; thank you very much